# javascript one letter function names in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I noticed that the production version of jquery has one-letter function and variable name and was wondering how they achieve that. are there tools to create a production level javascript file from the one use during development? I am having a hard time figuring out how they make sure there are no mistakes, especially for an open source project that big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript minfiers do this for them. Two good ones that shrink private variables names are [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) and [/packer/](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/).

Answer (score 0):

You would use one of many [JS minifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29) like JSMin or [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) to achieve such results.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "minification" or "packing" and there's a lot of different tools which can do it for you, for example: [Dean Edwards's Packer](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/) or [YUI Compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to JS minification, like YUI Compressor

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/